# Should we use anonymous classes for OnClickListeners or inner named classes?

Tags: java, android

I have lots of buttons in my Activity, I have the following questions:

1. Should I create multiple inner anonymous classes for OnClickListeners for each button, like below:

   ```
   private View.OnClickListener mShuffleListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           /// task to do
       }
   };
   ```
2. Or should I go for a named inner class and add an if condition to check which click listener was called.

Which one is better to save memory resources?

Comment: Whatever suits you!!...I would suggest going for a named inner class, if you want a well structured code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which one is cool to save mem resources?

It will make hardly any difference.  At most 1 word ... and that is comparing a static inner class with a (non-static) anonymous class.  A saving as small as that is not worth the code readability / maintainability penalty, even (IMO) if you've got a *hundreds* of these buttons.

Comment: I have almost 15 buttons in a activity,, if define 15 anonymous classes it will take 15*8 bytes of memory for reference, if i go for named inner class and implement cliklistener, it will save almost 14*8 bytes.. what say?

Comment: 1) Only if they are `static`.  If not, there is no saving.  2)  It is probably 14 * 4 bytes.  And that's a ridiculously small amount of memory to worry about.  3) If you have a 64-bit Android platform and hence 8-byte references, this is even more ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to handle event. Please have a look on the following link

http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/

See the following to know the use of anonymous class and inner class

**anonymous class**

> Use anonymous inner classes if you want the code not to be used
>   anywhere else (this class is being used just here and nowhere else.)

**inner class**

> inner class code can be used (if only by the class that created it if
>   made private). If you see a named inner class, someone might think
>   it'd be used in multiple places in the class.

Comment: Suppose i have 10 buttons , if i create 10 anonymous classes for each listener,it will create 10 new objects hence 10*8 bytes, but if i go with Named inner class and have check for all the 10 buttons to see which one is clicked , I could save 9*8 bytes. ?? what you say on this

Comment: @Ankit In this case why don't you use implements keyword. What you say about this?

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer a more subtle approach which makes the code easier to read when using onClick listener

There is a property called onClick for almost all the widgets in the properties menu(also available in the layout xml), there you can write a method name Ex xyz

now go to your java source file there you simply write a method
Ex

```
public void xyz(View v)
{
//your code goes here
}
```

and you are done .Also if you really wanna use inner classes then go with anonymous ones if memory is you concern(each reference stored takes 8 bytes of memory in java if its a reference type which in this case it is).

hope this helps..please do ask if you need more clarification

Comment: Suppose i have 10 buttons , if i create 10 anonymous classes for each listener,it will create 10 new objects hence 10*8 bytes, 
but if i go with Named inner class and have check for all the 10 buttons to see which one is clicked , I could save 9*8 bytes. ??
what you say on this

Comment: yup its true for storing the references in another variable because afterall you store references of objects and those references has to be stored somewhere .But for the objects(10*8 is a wrong assumption) you can't be sure how much memory it will take as it may again contain other references inside itself plus primitive types. An object can contain other objects too.

Answer (score 1):

If all buttons have similar functionality that differs only in a parameter that is identifiable, it is better to create one listener and assign it to all buttons.

The location of the listener is dependent of the scope of variables it need to use. If it needs to use some method variables, it should be created inside the method, if it uses a class members, it should be created inside the class.

For example, if you have ten buttons that each should start a different activity, you can create a map of views and activities, and in the listener fund the appropriate activity to start:

```
Map<View, Class<?>> viewActivityMap = new HashMap<View, Class<?>>();
// fill it somewhere

// in onCreate
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class<?> classToStart = viewActivityMap.get(v);
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, classToStart);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

In case of listeners, the only real reason I see to create an inner class, is if you want to create a constructor that receives parameters that are different from the implemented class/interface constructors.

Comment: I have to call some methods on clicking buttons,
I am thinking to have one inner named class implements ClickListener  and have if else condition which will check which button is clicked.
or should i go for create listeners by creating inner annony classes for each button.?

Comment: If the functionality is different, I would create separate listeners with one implementation each, if the functionality is somewhat similar, I would use the same one.

Comment: Thanks for this, as i can see in android source they are also creating different listeners for different buttons.