# using Anonymous inner class - conflicts in adding listeners and passing instances

Tags: java, android, listener, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I am newbie in android and learning first time.

I am making a very simple snippet something like when user clicks the button, the app should show a Toast message.

I have read many tutorials on the web. All tutorials I have seen on the web uses `anonymous inner class` to implement `listeners` and their methods.

What I have tried is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mTrue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTrue= (Button) findViewById(R.id.turebutton);


        mTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

}
```

It works perfectly, but seems difficult in understanding.

I am familiar with Java basics. i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679363/should-we-user-anonymous-classes-for-button-click-listener-or-inner-named-class) and I already know about `inner class` and  `anonymous inner class` in `java`.

In `java`,if we code something like this sample,

```
public void init(){
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
                       showStatus("mouse pressed");
             }
      });
}
```

the `MouseListener` is an interface and then we make instance of `MouseAdapter` and pass it to call `Listener`'s method on it.

I have some questions:

1. Why we have passed the instance of interface  (`View.onClickListener`) here?..i have checked the documentation, `View.onClickListener` is an interface not the class.
2. `setonClickListener` is looking same like `addMouseListener`. but the conflicting thing is In java, we had to `add` Listeners and `pass` instances of class. here things are inverse.

I am totally wired. please help if anyone can explain well. thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to know why do is `View.` added before `OnClickListener`?

Comment: @blackbelt yes and also i want to know about why things are different in android than we code in Java?(only in the context of my question)

Comment: 1. not instance of interface but instance of anonymous class(in-place interface implementation) 2. not java but awt ... it doesn't matter ... unless you need class that should extend 2 other classes ... it is not possible in java ... thats why interfaces are (IMHO) better in such places(simple UI events)

Comment: @Selvin can you please explain better in answer?

Comment: in both cases you are passing anonymous class instance: in first example this class is implementing interface, in second extends class ... anyway with such code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.java  MouseAdapter could be interface, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Here you are passing an instance of an anonymous class implementing the `View.OnClickListener()` interface.

The `setOnClickListener` method of `View` class accepts a parameter of type `View.OnClickListener`. Therefore, giving an instance that implements this interface works.

As for `addMouseListener`, assuming you are referring to [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29) of `Component`, it accepts an interface too - `MouseListener`.

However, in your example :

```
public void init(){
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
                       showStatus("mouse pressed");
             }
      });
}
```

you are passing to it an instance of an anonymous class that inherits from `MouseAdapter`, which itself implements the interface `MouseListener`.

Those two examples are therefore quite similar.

Comment: it is a method of `View` not of `Button`

Comment: How come this answer got a down vote just 5 seconds after it was posted?. Downvoter please explain yourself.

Comment: @blackbelt My mistake. I saw this method in the class reference of Button and missed the fact that it's inherited from View.

Answer (score 1):

**Why we have passed the instance of interface (View.onClickListener) here?..i have checked the documentation, View.onClickListener is an interface not the class.**

Here, `new View.OnClickListener() {..` means you am creating an instance of an anonymous class which implements `View.OnClickListener` *interface*.

**setOnClickListener is looking same like addMouseListener. but the conflicting thing is In java, we had to add Listeners and pass instances of class. here thing are inverse.**

Here you are adding a click listener to the button mTrue. check- `mTrue.setOnClickListener`.
The `setOnClickListener()` sets the listener to your button

Comment: ok..thanks for first answer..i understood it.but i can't understand the second answer. setOnClickListener is the method of View class...Should it not be a method of listener interface?

Comment: No, `setOnClickListener` is a method of you Button here, and it's logical since the button has to be observable.